# Custom Magento theme not extending from custom parent theme

Tags: magento2, custom-theme, inheritance

So I'm working on creating a custom parent theme I can reuse for a bunch of different projects and then a child theme for custom styles for a client to extend from that theme.

I had the custom child theme extending from the custom for a little while then one morning I came on and the custom child theme was no longer extending from the parent. Both themes do work.

This is the theme.xml for the custom parent

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>Acadaca Base</title>
    <parent>Magento/blank</parent>
    <media>
        <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image>
    </media>
</theme>
```

This is the theme.xml for the custom child

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
   <title>Equipment Base</title>
   <parent>Acadaca/base</parent>
   <media>
       <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image>
   </media>
</theme>
```

Can anyone offer any advice?